# Can't change iframes onload listener in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, onload

I have the following code within an external javascript file.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    //////////////////////UPCOMING EVENTS JSON SERVER START///////////////////////////

    var eventList = $("#eventList"); //cache the element
    $.getJSON("/JsonControl/Events.json", function (jsonObj) {
        val = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.events.length; ++i) {
            val += "<p>" + jsonObj.events[i].dateMonth + "/" + jsonObj.events[i].dateNumber +
                "/" + jsonObj.events[i].dateYear + " - <span id='EL" + i + "' class='link' " + 
                "onclick=plotEvent(" + i +")>" + jsonObj.events[i].title + "</span></p>";
        }
        eventList.html(val);
    });

    //////////////////////UPCOMING EVENTS JSON SERVER END/////////////////////////////

});

function plotEvent(index)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/JsonControl/Events.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (jsonObj) 
        {
            var eventBox = window.frameElement;
            alert("This alert fires in all browsers, including IE9")
            eventBox.onload = function () 
            {
                alert("This alert doesn't fire in IE9.")
                window.frameElement.onload = null; // unset it so it only fires once
                eventBox = eventBox.contentDocument || eventBox.contentWindow.document;
                eventBox.getElementById("title").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[index].title);
                eventBox.getElementById("content").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[index].explanation);
                eventBox.getElementById("dateHolder").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[index].dateMonth + "-" + jsonObj.events[index].dateNumber + "-" + jsonObj.events[index].dateYear);
            };
            eventBox.src="/Event htms/Event.htm";
        }
    });
}
```

The page that loads this script is in the iframe itself.  A very similar function called in a different external js file, from the main page outside of the iframe (for a different but similar purpose) works in all browsers just fine. The only difference is that with this code I have to target the onload of the iframe from within the iframe, instead of just grabbing the iframe by id. I then attempt to change, the onload of said iframe, for use with the next internal iframe page (which is why I need to preserve the json array index [i] when dynamically writing the first iframe page's innerHTML.

Sorry if that was a bit wordy, and/or confusing, but suffice it to say that with using the above-pasted code, I have no problems... except with IE (tried in IE9). I have tried dozens of examples and supposed solutions, but nothing has worked. Using IE9.

Here's what I mean when I say 'it doesn't work in IE9':

This part of the code within plotEvent() doesn't fire:

```
eventBox.onload = function () 
        {
            alert("This alert doesn't fire in IE9.")
            window.frameElement.onload = null; // unset it so it only fires once
            eventBox = eventBox.contentDocument || eventBox.contentWindow.document;
            eventBox.getElementById("title").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[index].title);
            eventBox.getElementById("content").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[index].explanation);
            eventBox.getElementById("dateHolder").innerHTML = (jsonObj.events[index].dateMonth + "-" + jsonObj.events[index].dateNumber + "-" + jsonObj.events[index].dateYear);
        };
```

Is there any solution to this problem, or is this sort of thing why iframes aren't used more often (that is, that IE doesn't fully support them)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `eventBox.contentWindow.onload` or maybe `$(eventBox).load(function)`

Comment: Thanks for trying but neither of those solutions work, plus I have used very similar code in another external javascript file that executes from the main page, and it changes the iframes onload event just fine. It works with this:  var eventBox = document.getElementById("eventBox"); 
                        eventBox.onload = function (){//code here}

Comment: one more try: I use iframes all the time and only in IE9. this is  code I use most (hope it helps): 
var context = $('#iframe');
context.one('load', function(){
   alert('loaded');
});

Comment: I will give it a go, so that if it works I can accept your answer, however, it may take a while to convert back to how I had it yesterday (I gave up this morning and converted it to be handled server-side, although I would rather not have to do that for this page). I will let you know!

Comment: I just got through trying your final solution, but alas, to no avail.  I'm sure your code is fine, but I have a lot of external scripts with multiple document.ready, jQuery (function ($){}), and html onload events going, so maybe something is conflicting. Oh, well, I guess that's just another example of how C# is more powerful than JavaScript (not a fair comparison, I will grant, but I don't think it is quite apples to oranges either). I will just handle this server-side and let C# do it. It's faster anyway. Thank you, so much, for all of your help, and sry if I wasted your time.